# Prove that the language $A= \left \{ x\in\left \{ 0, 1 \right \}^{*}\mid\#\left ( 0, x \right )= \#\left ( 1, x \right ) \right \}$ is not regular.

Tags: formal-languages, automata, regular-language, regular-expressions

I initially tried using the [pumping lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages), with little success, albeit I still think it's possible. I've been directed that using the [Myhill-Nerode theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myhill%E2%80%93Nerode_theorem) would be optimal, but I'm struggling. I need to show that $A$ has infinitely many equivalence classes. I also need to know what those equivalence classes are. Anything to help me better understand this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A new knowledge

Comment: Another approach would be: if $A$ were regular, then the intersection of $A$ with the language matched by the regular expression $0^* 1^*$ would also be regular.  But that intersection is exactly $\{ 0^n 1^n \}$ which is a prototypical example for applying the pumping lemma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: For the Myhill-Nerode approach, define

$$d:\{0,1\}^*\to\Bbb Z:w\mapsto|w|_0-|w|_1\,.$$

Thus, for instance, $d(01001)=3-2=1$, while $d(111)=0-3=-3$. Show that $x$ and $y$ are in the same Myhill-Nerode equivalence class if and only if $d(x)=d(y)$.

Comment: Thank you, think that got me in the right direction!

Comment: @Paper-SSheets: You’re welcome!